# Case when then conditions without else

Tags: sql, hive, case, hiveql

i am trying to do something like below where i dont want consider numbers which are greater then 30 in the below condition but the case condition taking else condition by default and adding them as null in value_a.

```
CASE WHEN a<10 and a!=0
               THEN
               a
                WHEN a>10 and a<30
                THEN
                b
            END AS value_a
```

out is as below

```
value_a
 a
 b
 null
```

where as i want it to consider values only upto 30 and ignore other numbers
and output be like

```
value_a
a
b
```

Comment: You need a `<= 30` condition in the WHERE clause.

Comment: that is because you have a value of a which doesn't meet that condition, what if a >= 30

Comment: i want it to not consider the numbers greater than 30 and ignore them

Comment: Your case expression will always return something, either a specified value. or NULL. If you don't want NULL, don't select that row. I.e. use a WHERE clause condition to skip >= 30 rows.

Comment: @user3495160 check the solution below, you need where as filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to exclude the results where a >= 30 then use where clause to filter those results. And if you need a to be equal to 10 then you are missing the equal sign (adjusted below)

```
SELECT *,

CASE WHEN a<=10 and a!=0 THEN a
     WHEN a>10 and a<30 THEN b
            END AS value_a
```

**code 2**

```
select *,
case when transaction_type = 'c' and date < [enter date] THEN A
     when transaction_type = 'c' and date > [enter date] THEN B
    else end as final_value
    FROM [table name] 
    WHERE transaction_type != 'd'
```

Comment: i have both tran=C and tran=D transactions.. i want to apply conditions only on credit like...... (case when tran='C' and date<20 then A when tran='C' and date >20 then B )and ignore all tran with 'D'

Comment: @user3495160 use the second code from above, you will just have to add your date conditions and alsoyou have not specified what would you want to do if data = 20 , you can adjust the case when there

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add '=' if you want to include 10 in your first condition.
You will also need to add '=' ifd you want to include 30 in your second condition.

At the end you will have to say you do not want to process if it is bigger than 30.

```
select CASE WHEN id<=10 and id>=0 THEN
            'a'
            WHEN id > 10 and id<=30 THEN
            'b'
            END value_a
from A
where id <= 30
```

Here is a small demonstration for SQLServer: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c488a9b78ccad196d374213db0cef98)
I believe it will help even if it is not in HIVEQL

Comment: i have both tran=C and tran=D transactions.. i want to apply conditions only on credit like...... (case when tran='C' and date<20 then A when tran='C' and date >20 then B   )and ignore all tran with 'D'

Comment: You can apply all that I have answered you above. You add this : select case when tran='C' and date<20 then A when tran='C' and date >=20 then B end value_a from YOUR_TABLE where tran<>D